# Does a Honda Civic send vehicle telemetry to its servers?

Tags: privacy, vehicle, gps

I recently read an article by the IEEE on [Tesla's vehicle telemetry](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tesla-autopilot-data-scope) and after reading that, I also realised that Honda Civics also have vehicle infotainment systems, including in-cabin microphones.

However, I couldn't find any resources online regarding Honda's policy on vehicle telemetry (including GPS) being sent to its servers. So does Honda Civics send vehicle telemetry to its servers?

Comment: This is answered with a simple google search. The answer below quotes Honda, and I was able to find it independently using the search term "honda civic send telemetry".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer from the manufacturer is trivially found online.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:  Yes, they record and capture a variety of information.  Including what is listed below.  In the reference document it discusses this and much more including only using voice recordings if you contact them or get into an accident.

> We collect Covered Information provided to us by you or retrieved by us from your vehicle or smart device
> (including applications thereon). The categories of Covered Information we collect may include:
> • Personal Identifiers and Contact Information such as your name, login username & password, device identifier,
> address, email address, and phone number;
> • Calls and Other Communication Recordings and Logs with our customer service team or service providers,
> such as recordings and logs of telephone calls, or communications using Connected Vehicle Technologies
> and Services;
> • Commercial Information such as your vehicle information number (“VIN”);
> • Information about Vehicle Operation and Performance such as:
>
> - Oil life, odometer mileage, fuel level, miles remaining to empty, dashboard warning lamps, tire pressure,
>   battery life, battery charge status, coolant temperature, engine rotations per minute, diagnostic trouble codes (e.g., electronic system generated trouble or failure codes), vehicle maintenance status, and other vehicle status and diagnostic information;
> - Trip log information, including trip start time and end time, trip start and end location, trip distance, and fuel consumed;
> - Airbag system status, including airbag deployment and the relative change in velocity (delta-v) associated
>   with airbag deployment (as noted above, information recorded on the SRS ECU is not collected);

> • Information about Use of Connected Vehicle Technologies and Services such as
>
> - Search content;
> - HondaLink or AcuraLink account access information, including information about anyone making a call
>   using the Connected Vehicle Technologies and Services;
> - Call history information, including the date, time, and duration of a call, and any response specialist’s
>   notes written during a call;
> - Navigation system settings and usage;
> - Audio system settings and usage;
> - Voice commands given (which may include audio recordings);
> - Connectivity systems (e.g., embedded TCU, Wi-Fi hotspot) settings and usage;

> • Geolocation Information meaning the exact location of your vehicle at a specific point in time or over a period
> of time;
> • Driver Behavior Information such as vehicle speed, vehicle acceleration and deceleration, pedal positions, engine speed, direction of travel, time of travel, steering angle, yaw rate, vehicle control systems settings/position/usage, Honda Sensing/Acura Watch system settings and usage.

**Reference**
[Honda Privacy Policy](https://www.honda.com/privacy/connected-product-privacy-policy.pdf)